# How to send both object and parameters in postman?

Tags: java, spring, api, rest, postman

I want to send an object of arraylist(in java) and other parameters as passed by the user to postman.

Here is my Code for controller

```
        @PostMapping(path = "/listEmpPaidSalariesPaged", produces = "application/json")

        public List<EmployeeSalaryPayment> listEmpPaidSalariesPaged
        (long SID, Collection<Student> student, String orderBy,
        int limit, int offset)
```

I know you can use RAW data and JSON for object 
and x-www-form-urlencoded for parameters, but how to send them together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use @RequestBody and @RequestParam annotations, like for example:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/listEmpPaidSalariesPaged", produces = "application/json")
public List<EmployeeSalaryPayment> listEmpPaidSalariesPaged(@RequestBody StudentRequestModel studentRequestModel, @RequestParam(value = "orderBy", defaultValue = "descending") String orderBy, @RequestParam(value = "limit", defaultValue = "25") int limit, @RequestParam(value = "offset", defaultValue = "0") int offset) {
       // controller code
}
```

@RequestBody will automatically deserialize the HttpRequest body (raw JSON from postman) into a java object (StudentRequestModel). 
@RequestParam will extract your query parameters (in postman you can do a POST to /listEmpPaidSalariesPaged?orderBy=ascending for example) into the defined variables. 
You can do both at the same time of course in postman.